# How NOT to synchronise fax numbers to the phone from Gmail contacts?

Tags: contacts, 4.2-jelly-bean, stock-android

I have Google Contacts with all the details needed for a contact. But I do not want to have fax numbers on my phone as they're useless. Is it possible to filter out just the fax numbers or the other way - to have just the home and work number for the contacts? Stock 4.2 android.